# Is it possible to width-wise shrink-wrap content that spans more than one line?

Tags: javascript, css

If I have an element contained in a box:

```
+-------- box --------+
| *------------*      |
| | small text |      |
| *------------*      |
+---------------------+
```

`display: inline-block` does the trick of shrink-wrapping it just fine. However, if the content spans more than one line because of the constrained width, it fails to shrink-wrap the element.

```
+-------- box --------+
| *-----------------* |
| | this does not   | |
| | shrink          | |
| | appropriately   | |
| *-----------------* |
+---------------------+
```

Is there any way of producing the desired result seen below?

```
+-------- box --------+
| *---------------*   |
| | this does not |   |
| | shrink        |   |
| | appropriately |   |
| *---------------*   |
+---------------------+
```

Here is a fiddle showing the two cases: http://jsfiddle.net/urLa8jvc/2/ and a solution where I manually break the line at the correct place to show the desired outcome.
A CSS solution is preferred, but javascript is also acceptable.

Comment: What you need here is for the parent block to get its width based on the computed width of the content.  CSS does not work that way, width's are passed on from parent to child.  To go the other way, setting the parent block width based on the child/content width, you will need a JavaScritpt/jQuery assisted solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd really much prefer the solution to be CSS, but for now I've written this "hack" that does the trick using javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/86khx8kf/2/

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".node");
for (var nidx = 0; nidx < nodes.length; nidx++) {
    var node = nodes[nidx];
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.split(" ").map(function (word) {
        return "<span>" + word + "</span>";
    }).join(" ");
    var spans = node.querySelectorAll("span");
    var offsetLeft = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
    for (var sidx = 0; sidx < spans.length; sidx++) {
        var span = spans[sidx];
        if (span.offsetLeft <= offsetLeft) {
            node.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), span);
        }
        offsetLeft = span.offsetLeft;
        span.outerHTML = span.innerHTML;
    }
    node.normalize();
}
```

Comment: Is this still the best solution in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `max-width` property to you `.node` class :

```
.node {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #999;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

see your jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/urLa8jvc/4/

Comment: I have many "nodes", and the appropriate width is not the same for all of them. The exact size would also vary depending on the font available, and probably other factors, so hand-picking a max-width (which is really just like changing the width of the constraining element) will not work. (Even if the text was static and known beforehand)

Comment: What about using percentage based max width `max-width: 50%;` ? What are your criterias for the size of the "node" ?

Comment: I need the nodes to be as wide as possible within the constrained width, but not wider than the widest resulting line in the node (though still respecting the padding set on the node).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of your node divs in a span, then use javascript to set their widths to that of the span.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="node"><span>Short text</span></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="node"><span id="weird">Something that takes up more than one line for real tho</span></div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.node').width(function() {
        var first = $(this).children().first();
        var width = first.width() + 1;
        return width;
    });

    $('.node').each(function(){
        var first = $(this).children().first();
        first.css('display', 'inline-block')
    });
</script>
```

This works because spans are inline-elements, and so will be as narrow as possible.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmsuzo7b/2/

Edit:

While this worked in Chrome, Firefox appears to handle text layout in multiline spans slightly differently. To compensate for this, we need to add an extra pixel to the width of the parent div. In addition, changing the width of the parent div was causing the inner span to be laid out again in Firefox, thus shrinking its width. To prevent this from happening, we set the spans to `display: inline-block` so that they now fill the full width of their newly resized parent div.

Anyway, you may need to tinker with the padding for this slightly, but I doubt the extra pixel will be noticeable.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, but doesn't seem to work entirely as I had hoped. This is how your solution looks: http://i.imgur.com/R3WaBgn.png and this is how it should look http://i.imgur.com/b1yCisP.png

Comment: Interesting. "up" is on the first line in Chrome, but the second in Firefox. Looking into this now.