# How do I shrink a flex item around a text-wrapped span?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm not even sure if this is possible, I'm trying to figure out if I can shrink a flex item around a span that is text-wrapped.

This is where I'm at now, if you look at the second row, I'm trying to eliminate whitespace to the right of the text.

```css
body {
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body > div {
  min-height: 55px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 225px;
}
body > div > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
body > div > div span {
  font-size: 21px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>Some text regular</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div><span>howdoishrinkthis flexitemtotext</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div><span>Some text regular</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to shrink the font size? I'm not sure I understand what you want to do

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with pure CSS. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25808069/3597276

Comment: If you inspect the span inside the "howdoishrinkthis flexitemtotext", it has a smaller width than the flex item. Essentially, I want the  to be flush against the text to the left.

Comment: It seems like the layout gets calculated before the text wraps and never gets recalculated. If you replace the space with an explicit `<br/>` tag, for example, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `flex-basis` to zero, you will shrink a flexible item to its minimum size.
So it will fit to the text, but it will also force your text to wrap:

```css
body > div {
  min-height: 55px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 225px;
}
body > div > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
body > div > div span {
  font-size: 21px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 0;
          flex: 0 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>Some text regular</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div><span>howdoishrinkthis flexitemtotext</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution seems to only work on newer versions of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below isn't perfect, but it does pull the flex item up to the text even for long words. It accomplishes this by:

1. Floating the text container (the `span`)
2. Breaking long words (and hyphenating them in browsers that support hyphenation)

```css
body {
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body > div {
  min-height: 55px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 225px;
}
body > div > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
body > div > div span {
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>Some text regular</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div><span>howdoishrinkthis flexitemtotextevenlonger and more and more and mroe text</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div><span>Some text regular asdf asdf</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```