# CSS shrink width when text wrapped into multi-lines

Tags: html, css

I'm building a list widget where I have multiple `<li>` with two sibling elements wrapped inside.

A `<span>` for the title and a `<div>` for the bottom line. That line must vary depending the width of their adjacent span element.

```css
.limit-area {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
}
.limit-area ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
.limit-area ul li {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.limit-area ul li .wrapper span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #010101;
}
.limit-area ul li .wrapper .line {
  height: 6px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit-area">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <span>One line only</span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <span>Bigger one line only </span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <span>Long line and go crazyyyyyy</span>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Full example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arnauth/55josw6e/

In the upper example, I can easily accomplish my goal on the first two list items.

The trick here is to have the same effect when I have a long line that break into two or more lines - that third line on the example.

The line element must have the same width of the text, so **in the example must stop near the word 'go' - not in the end of the container** as displayed.

The idea is try to approach the problem using **only CSS** rules avoiding javascript based code.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you want to have red underline for each line or only in the bottom?

Comment: Almost the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25808069/483779 there are couple of JS attempts.

Comment: I'm searching a way to do it only with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside of your span:

```
border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6f69;
```

so that it ends up looking like this:

```
span {
          font-size: 24px;
          color: #010101;
          border-bottom: 6px solid #ff6f69;
        }
```

it should come out like this
https://jsfiddle.net/55josw6e/3/

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Inje, like the approach, but the widget uses multiple WebKit animations during the navigation, so the `<div>` element for the line must be present.